# graph limit problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, rational-functions

[image]

For this given graph, since it approaches positive infinity from the left and right sides of $x=2$, shouldn't $\lim_{x \to 2} g(x) = \infty$? Or would its value not exist (as it says in my homework answer key)?

Comment: The value at $x=2$ does not exist. The limit exists and is $\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the graph,

$$\lim_{x\to 2, x <2}g (x)=+\infty $$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 2, x>2}g (x)=+\infty $$

thus
$$\lim_{x\to 2, x\ne 2}g (x )=+\infty $$

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a value $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$ as a solution of this limit, then the limit would not exist. Remember that the definition of limit for a real valued function says as follows:

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined on the real line and $p,\ell\in\mathbb{R}$. It is said the limit of $f$, as $x$ approaches $p$, is $\ell$ and written
>   $$\lim_{x\to p} f(x)=\ell,$$
>   if the following property holds: for every real $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a real $\delta > 0$ such that for all real $x$, $0 < | x − p | < \delta$ implies $| f(x) − \ell | < \varepsilon$.

**But** limits can also have infinite values. Sometimes, rather than say that a limit is infinity, the proper thing is to say that the function *diverges* or *grows without bound*. In any case, the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is infinity, denoted
$$\lim _{x\to a}f(x)=\infty,$$
means that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

Deciding what to answer in your homework is up to you. You should review your notes and check how your professor defined limits.